# How can I prevent the user from accessing a session without logging in to my application developed with Flask and Pyrebase4?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

I'm totally a newbie learning Flask and I'm trying to implement a login and logout system with Pyrebase4. I have the following doubt, how can I prevent the user from being able to access the URL without authenticating? The following program allows the user to login and logout, but it does not prevent the user from accessing the information that requires login by visiting the URL. Please help. What I want is that the user cannot access the 'tasks' session if he has not been authenticated.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import pyrebase

app = Flask(__name__)

config = {
    'apiKey': "here",
    'authDomain': "here",
    'projectId': "here",
    'storageBucket': "here",
    'messagingSenderId': "here",
    'appId': "here",
    'measurementId': "here",
    'databaseURL':""
  }

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

auth = firebase.auth()

app.secret_key='hufrhhfhrjfbrekjfberufureye4674656486435hjjjfhhkjsh'

texto = ""  

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    #if ('user' in session):
        #return 'Hi, {}'.format(session['user'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        try:
            user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            session['user'] = email
        except:
            return 'Password or login incorrect'
        
        return redirect(url_for("tasks"))
    
    return render_template('home.html')
        
        
      
@app.route('/tasks', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def tasks():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global texto
        texto = request.form['texto']
        
        texto = len(texto)
                
    return render_template('tasks.html', texto=texto)       
        
        
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('user')
    return redirect('/')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**'templates' folder**

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <form action='/' method='POST'>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**tasks.html**

```
<h1>

Welcome to tasks!!!!

</h1>


<form action="{{ url_for('tasks')}}" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Text: <input type="text", name='texto'><br>
    <input type='submit'>


</form>


{{texto}}


<a href="{{url_for('logout')}}">LogOut</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the flask_login library mentioned above by @Adam, you can also use wraps from functools to create custom decorators for your routes. Custom meaning, you can create any logical conditions you desire, say you have a User role called 'Super Admin', you could creator a decorator such as this ->

```
from functools import wraps

from flask import flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_login import current_user

def super_admin_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user.role == "Super Admin":
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash("You need to be an Admin to view this page.")
            return redirect(url_for('account'))

    return wrap
```

And then import to your routes file and use as a decorator for a given class, you can also use as many decorators as you'd like for a given route. For example ->

```
from flask_login import login_required
from projectroot.decorators import super_admin_required

@app.route("/super_admin_panel", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@super_admin_required
def super_admin_panel():
    # interesting things here
```

Be sure to read the docs about how to use the flask_login module correctly. Essentially it will require you set up your User table with particular column names, as well as including UserMixin as an argument in the class declaration; for example ->

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    etc...
```